# Google docs on Android cannot authenticate

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, google-drive, sprint

I have a Galaxy S3 on Sprint with the latest software and firmware updates. When I use the internet browser to browse to `docs.google.com`, it keeps redirecting me between `accounts.google.com` and then back to `docs.google.com`. It does it so fast I can't type in my password to authenticate.

This has persisted across a reboot. I am logged in to my google account if I go to `Settings`, `Accounts`.

I just want to get on to Google Docs. How do I stop this redirection? (note this method worked fine on another phone of the same make/model.)

Comment: Even if if goes from docs > accounts > docs, you are still logged-in to docs (correctly) right?

Comment: @geffchang I don't think it's logged in appropriately. At least not for google docs. It basically leaves up the authentication page where I type my password, but keeps stealing the focus when the URL bar switches, killing the keyboard display so I can't type my password. Very odd.

Comment: Have you tried using a different browser (e.g. Boat Browser), and see if it's also doing the same?

Comment: I haven't tried another browser. I'll do that.

Comment: @geffchang I tried Firefox. It let me authenticate for the first time, then after I had given it my password, it started doing the same thing. I cleared cache, history, and cookies, and was able to get the authentication page again, with the same results when I signed in. If I used the wrong password when I signed in, this did not happen. It wasn't until I authenticated. Does this have something to do with the google account I'm using on the phone for email? It's the same account.